# Remove disconnected structures of compounds

Tags: java-stream, cheminformatics

I am uploading 3 different chemical files to my application, one at a time. Each file contains `SMILE` of compound, but the tag name is different. I am creating an `IAtomContainer` stream by reading file. I want to remove the disconnected structures from the stream. Is there any way to remove it instead of manually checking `SMILES`. I am using cdk 1.5.13.

Comment: This question might belong on the chemistry site.

Comment: no its  for java application. I am using chemistry development kit for develop this application. and its relating to Cheminformatics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConnectivityChecker.isConnected(IAtomContainer);
```

this is working. Its returning boolean value.